# In wpf, when I press button it closes all stackpanels. I need to close the specific stackpanel when button is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

As I said in title, I need to close the button interacted stackpanel item when close button is pressed. But I'm new in wpf and can't understand how to bind stackpanel or button with specific stackpanel item. Can you please help me ?

```
`<DataTemplate x:Key="fixTemplate">
    <Grid Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel  x:Name="fixPanel" MouseWheel="StackPanel_MouseWheel">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" Opacity="1.0" Background="{dxi:ThemeResource {dxmt:MapBrushesThemeKey ResourceKey=OverlayBackground}}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="8">
                    <Button x:Name="fixButton" Uid="0++" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}}" Content="X" Background="Red" Width="25" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="fixButton_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="fixText" Text="{Binding ToolTipText}" Foreground="{dxi:ThemeResource {dxmt:MapBrushesThemeKey ResourceKey=OverlayElementForeground}}"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <Path Stretch="Fill" 
              Data="m 66.709675,141.93548 29.096774,-33 27.677421,33.35484 -18.80645,-0.35484 0.70968,43.29032 H 87.64516 l -0.709676,-43.29032 z"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Height="15"
              Width="20"
              UseLayoutRounding="False"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Stroke="#BF000000" 
              StrokeThickness="0.4"
              Margin="-13 0 0 0" >
                <Path.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" BlurRadius="7" Opacity="0.5"/>
                </Path.Effect>
                <Path.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1." />
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>
        </StackPanel>                
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>`
```

As you see I have a button and dynamically created stackpanels. How can I delete the stackpanel that it's button is clicked ?

I tried to delete stackpanel which is under it's delete button but every stackpanel is deleted in my code. I don't know how to specify which stackpanel will deleted when that stackpanel's close button is pressed

Comment: Can u attach your code behind ?

Comment: My code behind has 83000 character so I can't paste it here.

Comment: You should create a simple demo example just demonstrating the part of the code that is causing you trouble. You can leave out all markup instructions, unless they are essential for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding checkbox to stack panel

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" Opacity="1.0" Background="{dxi:ThemeResource {dxmt:MapBrushesThemeKey ResourceKey=OverlayBackground}}">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="8">
       <CheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTipText}" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=MyCheckBox, Converter={dxmvvm:BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Foreground="{dxi:ThemeResource {dxmt:MapBrushesThemeKey ResourceKey=OverlayElementForeground}}"  TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

and this code in model view

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var isChecked = (bool)value;
        return isChecked ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code behind for what i tried is this

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (depObj != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

                if (child != null && child is T)
                    yield return (T)child;

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }

    private void fixButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string tooltip = "";
        List<string> ttlist = new List<string>();
        foreach (var textblock in FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(this))
        {
            if (textblock.Name == "fixText")
            {
                tooltip = textblock.Text;
                ttlist.Add(tooltip);
            }
            break;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < RealTimeMapDataGeneratorModel.sb.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(tooltip);
            System.Console.WriteLine(RealTimeMapDataGeneratorModel.sb[i].ToolTipText);
            if (ttlist[i] == RealTimeMapDataGeneratorModel.sb[i].ToolTipText)
            {
                //SubmarineVectorLayer.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                RealTimeMapDataGeneratorModel.Submarine.RemoveAt(i);
                RealTimeMapDataGeneratorModel.sb.RemoveAt(i);
            }

        }
    }
```